# Partitioning code into assemblies for the sake of logical seperation

Tags: deployment, qa, projects-and-solutions, dll

I've started working at this company, and the software is managed in a Visual Studio solution that includes hundreds of projects (C++ and C#).
After poking around the solution for couple of weeks, I started wondering why there are so many projects. Not only does it slows down VS considerably, but a rebuild can take up to an hour.

Since a visual studio project corresponds to a physical deployment unit (be it a .NET dll, a C++ lib or an exe), there are reasons why you'd want code partitioned across projects. Some of those reasons can be found in [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/partitioning-your-code-base-through-.net-assemblies-and-visual-studio-projects/).

In my particular case, none of the reasons in that article stood. There are roughly 5 processes running across tiers, maybe a few dynamically loaded assemblies used for a plug-in model, and some infrastructure which is rarely changed.

I don't see any need for more than ~50 VS projects for this solution, and I believe that merging them will increase productivity and will allow for a shorter feedback loop.

When I tried to suggest this to the software manager, his response was that they are trying to have **as many dlls as possible** so that when they plan to ship a new feature, **QA can test just the behavior of the modified dlls** without having to worry that something else was effected. He said that since a dll was not changed, it will behave the same. For this to work they aim for high granularity of deployment units.

Does this make sense to anyone? I don't see the difference in the effect on behavior between  editing a single line in a project that has a single huge dll, and editing the same line in a project that includes hundreds of dlls.

**EDIT**

I'm looking for an answer on using assemblies/project as means for separating logical concerns and its effect on the testing effort. I would even go as far as saying that many assemblies that could give you more testing scenarios because of versioning incompatibilities.

So my distilled question is: When will you partition your code across projects/assemblies instead of namespaces in the same assembly, given that there are no runtime constraints, and why?

**EDIT 2**

I guess I'm looking for something like [this article](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2008/09/30/separate-assemblies-loose-coupling/). However, I'm reluctant to post this as an answer and accept before I see if there are different opinions in the community.

Comment: One thing that I've found useful in situations like that (a sprawling solution and political resistance to consolidation) is to create your own solutions that include relevant subsets of the projects.  This wipes out your long build/re-build times and makes the feedback loop much faster, especially if you are running some kind of continuous testing tool.  You only have to run the big solution's build before checkins.

Comment: @ErikDietrich That's exactly what I've started doing since that talk. What I'm trying to figure out from this question here, is if there is any justification for that manager's approach.

Comment: What do you think "DLL Hell" means? Strikes me that avoiding DLL Hell (mismatched versions used by different applications) is one of very few advantages of having all your projects in a single solution.

Comment: @pdr My problem is not with the large number of project in a single solution vs many solutions. It's about having many projects vs having less projects - in the same solution. see my edit

Comment: Then you're misusing the term. Having a lot of assemblies is not DLL hell. The problem you have here is that neither argument is particularly strong, like the spaces vs tabs argument, so all you're going to get is opinion. What you really should be asking is how you speed your build up. (Have you checked that you're not rebuilding, rather than building, and that you're not verbose logging unnecessarily?)

Comment: @pdr I guess I was misusing that term. I edited DLL Hell out. So what you're saying is that there is no additional cost in having many assemblies/project in a solution? That it can be used just as a tool for logical separation? I guess I'm looking to be convinced that assembly vs namespace is equivalent to spaces vs tabs

Comment: Note that one failure mode for this is code being included in more than one compiled unit. I've worked on one project where after ~5 years the average source file was in 2.5 output files, with a peak of 90% (ie, the same source file was in 9 out of every 10 compiled files). Unless you're rigorous about monitoring this it will happen (worst case, by copy'n'paste or independently duplicated functionality)

Comment: @Ӎσᶎ I'm not entirely sure what you mean here. I don't see the connection between partitioning code into assemblies and code/functionality duplication.

Comment: @moranlf: how do you avoid including the same code in more than one assembly? How do you avoid re-writing existing functionality? How big a chunk of duplication do you allow before extracting it into a common assembly? Or do you just not worry, and end up with most code included in more than one assembly? To me, the latter is a failure, and I think it's a common failure mode of the "hundreds of assemblies" model. Specifically in your case, if a common source file changes you need to rebuild every assembly that includes it. Unless you have a mechanical check, you will miss some.

Comment: @Ӎσᶎ Lets ignore C++ includes for the sake of the argument. In .NET you will never have the same code in several assemblies unless you either copy/paste or add the same source file to different assemblies - both are bad practices that should be avoided. I still see the discussion about duplication completely orthogonal to assembly partition. I could extract duplicated code/functionality to a shared class in the same assembly or extract to a shared assembly - it will be determined according to deployment/runtime constraints.

Comment: I've edited the title to better address the topic of the question. Also added a link to an opinion on the subject, I would love to hear your opinion, especially if it is different than what is stated in the article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QA as a whole is about assessing the risk that the product is suitable for the users to use.  In reality, QA is not a 100% guarantee in part because it is usually impossible to test every possible action (including all non valid actions) in every possible environment.

Since you have limited QA resource, you have to make decisions about where to focus that resource to increase the likelihood that you detect critical bugs that have been missed by the developers.

The QA's comment about DLL's not changing means they can focus their testing effort better is correct. Although, it's correctness is decreased if the library is not version stamped by the autobuild system (how do you prove its the same DLL?) and its getting close to wrong if its a new DLL compiled from the same source code  (did compiler options / toolset change - producing a different library?)...   and if there is no mechanism that the QA actually do to audit that the source code between the two DLL's have not changed then its definitely wrong as QA cannot say with any confidence that a change has not slipped in.

I've worked on several teams that have large numbers of projects in the same solution file. It worked better for some than others. Things deteriorate when the number of projects files increase to such a point that Visual Studio starts becoming unstable.  However, on a well designed architecture, that designs the DLL's inter-dependencies to a minimum and has a strong release and version management process it can be made to work well.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it. Lets assume for now that all dlls are signed and versioned such that QA knows exactly what changed (BTW, we also have source control for that). Wouldn't it be more safe to focus QA's effort on the change according to changes in source rather then the DLL? I return to the example in my question: given that QA knows that a single line was changed in a particular component (component here being a *logically* seperated entity), how will their testing focus change if the line is pacakged in a large dll or smaller dll?

Comment: QA is about managing risk. You have a limited time resource to provide your best effort at finding bugs. If you recompile the same source code and claim its the same DLL you are introducing risk that a code change occurred, that the compiler was updated on the build machine, that the source control had a glitch and left part of the previous build's source code there, that a DLL that this code depended on changed...  All these are risks that need to be managed and assessed as part of the risk assessment.

Comment: Your comment is on the spot. It makes me think why our scheduled build process always does a rebuild and automatically stamps all dlls with the current revision number...

Comment: I upvoted and accepted since I see that QA risk assessment is the reason for the manager's partitioning strategy. I still highly disagree that this assessment should be based on physical unit, but rather on logical, but that discussion probably doesn't belong here, on a Q&A site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think having too many projects in a single solution is a bad thing. I have previously worked on the system that comprised of over 15 business domains. If I was to put them all into one solution, than I would end up with hundreds of projects. I suggest that you try and break these projects down into logical solutions (domains). In other words, work on separation of concerns.

In regards to build time - this can normally be improved. We had a system that took over an hour to build and after a year of work the time went down to under 10 minutes, which is a massive cost saving.

Comment: I agree regarding a partitioning a large solution into smaller ones. But I'm looking for an answer with reasons to having a large number of projects in the first place, when their only function is a container around logical components. I guess this comes down to why having different projects instead of a single project with many namespaces, when there isn't deployment-related justification (like tier seperation, plug-ins etc.)

Comment: I'm guessing it was done as an attempt to separate concerns.

Comment: Right, but why are those concerns better separated when packaged in a different dll rather then a different namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does make a sense. The problem is it is still highly theoretical. I would question him if what he says, is really done in practice. Does QA really test individual DLLs or do they only test bigger parts of the project. Do they also test DLLs that have changed DLL as dependency? If no, how are they able to ensure it is also correctly working? There is also problem of actually tracking changes for each DLL. Because the more DLLs there are, the harder it is to track what DLLs were changed for specific feature/bugfix. Last thing that comes to mind is separation of concerns. If the structure of project is correct, then many changes would require change of only few DLLs. Preferably only one. This is rarely a case and more often than not, projects are in such a state that change propagates through many DLLs. In the end it is matter of compromise : Is the advantage of separate testing (with all that goes with it) higher than having really long build times and dealing with DLL hell?

I would definitely ask him, if what he says is just wishful thinking or real practice, that is actually advantageous.

Comment: I'm really interested in this "highly theoretical" sense. I have yet to find any proven justification for using VS projects for logical partitioning (except for the ones mentioned in the article). Isn't that what namespaces are for?

Comment: @moranlf VS projects are best used as modules/packages. In which case, things like software package metrics and dependencies between packages.
I'm just saying that while what your manager says is possible, it takes much more effort, than what person might think, to actually do right.